# Javascript: console.log time

Tags: javascript, php

I want to output in rough form how many milliseconds are between 2 events in my php code.

To do that, I was hoping to be able to display something like that with minimal code:

23:01:30:220 //meaning 23 hours, 1 min,30 seconds, 220 milliseconds

How do I add such a timestamp to the console log function?

```
console.log(event);
```

I have seen code that spans 5 lines, but I was hoping I could do something like

```
console.log(Time + " " + event);
```

Is there such an easy function?

Thank you.

Comment: Give a check on moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Comment: `console.log` is javascript code, which means it run in browser, for php you can do something like this: `$start = microtime(true); sleep(100); $elapsed = (microtime(true) - $start); echo "sleep took: $elapsed";`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use consloe.log in PHP but you can just simply try this code below:

```
$starttime = microtime(true); // Top of page
// Code
$endtime = microtime(true); // Bottom of page

printf("Page loaded in %f seconds", $endtime - $starttime );
```